# How can I convert some variables into numeric while keeping other variables same in R

Tags: r, lapply, data-cleaning, numeric

Here I use this code to convert the factors to numeric variables:

```
Table1_2[] <- lapply(Table1_2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

But It converts all the variables so I cant use The FIRM variable anymore in the below plot.
My question is how can I change only the variables I want into numeric while keeping some of them in their original version?

```
install.packages('remotes')


remotes::install_github("brunoruas2/gujarati",force = TRUE)

library(gujarati)


library(ggplot2)


Table1_2[] <- lapply(Table1_2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))


ggplot(Table1_2, aes(Table1_2$C.1, Table1_2$I) +geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Table1_2$FIRM)+theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

Comment: using`dplyr`: `Table1_2 %>% mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~as.numeric(as.character(.x))))`. Check `?dplyr_tidy_select ` for more tidy select possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform operations on subsets of dataframes (in your case only a few Cols) by restricting the Input and the overwritten variable of your cols. Lets say you want every column to be numeric except for  the column named `FIRM`:

```r
col_is_not_FIRM <- colnames(Table1_2) != "FIRM"
Table1_2[col_is_not_FIRM] <- lapply(Table1_2 [col_is_not_FIRM], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

`col_is_not_FIRM` in this case is a logical vector, telling the subsetting operation, which columns to select. You can find a few ways for subsetting in dataframes here: https://www.statology.org/subset-data-frame-in-r/

Note that you have to subset on the left side of `<-` as well as on the right side. Else R will attempt to cram a larger dataframe into a smaller one or vise versa.